# Django: Applying permissions in the URL dispatcher?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-permissions

In my Django application, I have certain permissions which users need in order to access certain views (using `django.contrib.auth`).  This works fine, using the `@permission_required` decorator on my view functions.

However, some of my URLs resolve to views which I did not write, such as the built-in `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change`, as in the following `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
 (r'^$', "users.views.index"),
 (r'^password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'))
```

In this instance, I have nowhere to apply my `@permission_required` decorator -- or do I?  Is there any way to apply a permissions restriction at the URL dispatcher level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to import the login required function and apply it to the generic view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', login_required(direct_to_template), {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
    )
```

as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140550/how-to-require-login-for-django-generic-views).

Comment: How would you use `permission_required` in the same way? Specifically how would you pass it the permission name argument?

Comment: @Manoj: check out this section of the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-generic-views the idea is to write a thin wrapper (with permission_required decorator) around the generic view, and point your urlconf to that wrapper...

Comment: That is what I did in my answer. Just wanted to know if there was any other way to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: I need a customized decorator, how can I create a customized permission check function to wrap the view function, thanks.

Comment: @stallman just write your own decorator, import it, and use it in place of login_required. A decorators really is just a function, and can be used like one...

Answer (score 18):

A decorator is a fancy word for a function that wraps another function. `login_required` is a wrapper function for a view while `permission_required` constructs a wrapper for your view. In other words, `login_required` is itself a decorator and `permission_required(perm)` constructs a decorator.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^public/', myview),

    url(r'^users_only/', 
        login_required(myview)),

    url(r'^users_with_perms/',
        permission_required('myapp.view_mymodel', login_url='login')(myview)),

    url(r'^login_page/', myloginview, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: you are the best! This answer is more intelligible the the chosen one

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to wrap the views you did not write.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change

@permission_required('my_perm')
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return password_change(*args, **kwargs)

#URLs
urlpatterns = patterns(
  (r'^$', "users.views.index"),
  (r'^password_change/$', 'wrapper'))
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a [little hack](https://github.com/yuexue/django_url_decr) about the Django URL resolver, you may apply a decorator at URL dispatch level:

```
from django_url_decr import url_decr
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = patterns(''
                       url_decr(r'^users/',
                                include('users.urls'),
                                decr=login_required))
```