# How to prevent the access to login page after successful login in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-login

Using the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` method to perform the sign in method in my project, how to prevent the access to the `/registration/login/` page again after successful login?

Comment: You could just redirect the user if they are logged in already and request /login/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could deocrate your login-view with this [AnonymousRequired](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1849/)-Decorator.

See this blog post for some background information on decorators which even explains things using your specific problem : http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/

Comment: I think if a user is logged in, it's normal to deny him the access again to the login form. Doesn't it?

Comment: About your approach, the problem is that I am using the django.contrib.auth.views.login method so I shouldn't modify it.

Comment: Using the decorator isn't modifying the view. You can apply the decorator in your urlpatterns.

Comment: Using a decorator in your urls.py is explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140550/how-to-require-login-for-django-generic-views/2140678#2140678. On the other hand it isn't too hard to write a custom login view and decorate it (or intercept calls from already logged in users), as Thierry suggests.

Answer (score 2):

In your login view, check if a user is already authenticated:

```
def your_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('yourhomepage') # or somewhere else or last url
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you want to keep authenticating that way, the only way I can think of redirecting is through a middleware.

1. Create a middleware
2. Check if the current url matches your login url
3. If user is already authenticated, redirect to home page, otherwise process as usual

Comment: Hi, it's correct but as I mentioned below I dont have my custom login view because I am using the django.contrib.auth.views.login and I can't modify it

Comment: Can you show the code where your are using the django login function?

Comment: Of course, is a simple mapping in my URLConf: (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')

Answer (score 0):

For check In your login view, check if a user is already authenticated or no you should take it:

```
def your_login(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('/') #redirect to your home page
```

It is correct

Thanks for confirming my answer