# Django 1.5 robots.txt

Tags: django, robots.txt

Here is what we have in our url conf:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
```

.....

```
url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.html')),
```

For some reason, we're getting redirected to ?next=robots.txt when attempting to hit *.com/robots.txt

Is there something obvious we're missing ? This seems to work locally in vagrant environments but it's not working in production (redirecting through ?next=)

update 1
There is no obvious reason that this would be behind a @login_required decorator or any required login function...

update 2
Sure enough, you can see robots.txt when you are authenticated....

update 3 direct_to_template has been deprecated, I'm sure that used to work but apparently has been deprecated in django 1.5

update 4 seems like this post has a way to force login_required for a TemplateView.as_view: [How to require login for Django Generic Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140550/how-to-require-login-for-django-generic-views) but it seems in our case this is being force by default ?

Comment: idk why TemplateView is requiring a login, but if you need to get it working you can just set up a normal function view and render your template that way, or if your file is not being dynamically generated, it should be served usign your webserver not through django

Comment: Do you have any middleware installed that might be interfering?