# How to make the login page the first page

Tags: python, django

I want to make the login page the first page appear to the user what should I write in the path?

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.home, name='home')
    #path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('', ??? ,name='login'),# what I should I put here to make login page the first page appear
    path('like/<int:pk>',LikeView,name='like_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-details'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/remove', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
    path('category-list/', CategoryListView, name='category-list'),
    
]
```

Comment: You should put the name of the view you are using.

Comment: Here is the problem i'm using Django forms

Comment: path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

Answer (score 2):

So you want to redirect unauthenticated users to Login page
You can use this MiddleWare:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login')) # Your login page url
        return None
```

And in your settings.py you need to add your MiddleWare:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'path.to.your.AuthRequiredMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the user to login before accessing *any* page, you can use a custom middleware. See the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399113/15369711
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123660/15369711

If you only need the user to login before accessing certain pages, you can use:

- `LoginRequiredMixin` for class-based views; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin
- the `@login_required` decorator for function-base views; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Answer (score 1):

I don't thinks it's the best way, but it's the easiest way to acomplish that.
On your html template just add this:

```py
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<body>
...
</body>

{% else %}

<script>
    window.location.href = '/login' // Your login page URL
</script>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I got it here is the solution

```
def LoginView(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

```
path('', LoginView ,name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

By using this:

1. path() type in urls.py

**path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).